# I'm having trouble understanding the properties of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt

[image]

The objective of this question is find beta, which is ( Ic/Ib)

The 3V is supposed to be 2.3V
The 27 k ohm is supposed to be 20k 
The 230 ohm is supposed to be 230 ohm

I first found Ib = 4.3 v- 2.3v / 20k = 10 mA,  and Ic is just 2.3 v - 0 / 230 = .1 mA.  Therefore B should be 10 mA/ .1 mA = 100, but the answer in the book is 99.

I see how they got the 99, which is just subtracting .1 mA from Ib and making that Ic, but why?

Comment: 1. Where do you get 2.3V from in your calculation for I_b? 2. Does it make sense to you that I_b is greater than I_c? 3. Given the voltage across the 750 ohm resistor, find the current through that resistor. Does that make sense, if your I_b or I_c are 10mA?

Comment: Your equations use resistor values of 20k\$\Omega\$ and 230\$\Omega\$. Where did you get those? Are you just trying to provoke someone to give you the answer?

Comment: Your circuit drawing does not match the equations (which are evaluated incorrectly)  Please revise

Comment: If the numbers you're using in your calculations are 'correct', then your transistor is broken.

Answer (score 0):

i looked closer and i realized the mistake i made i incorrectly performed KCL on the circuit.

the collector current goes into the node with the 2.3 voltage, and the current from the base and the current.

those two current must equal to the current across the 230 ohm resistor or in this case the 750.

then from there it's just KCL

Ib = (4.3 - 2.3)/20k = .1 uA

I230R is = 2.3 / 230 = 10mA

my KCL equation gave me : IB + IC = I230R ==> IC = I230R - Ib = 9.9mA

solving for beta gives me : B= Ic/Ib = 99

i reviewed my circuits book again, i guess i worded it pretty no bueno.